# Get Json request values in Java Service Task

Tags: java, business-process-management, camunda

Not able to read the JSON request values in Java Service Task

```
Input JSON

 {
  "variables": {
    "event":{
     "cat" : {"value" : "abc", "type" : "String"},
     "reason": {"value":"abc Changes","type":"String"},
     "link": {"value":"http://localhost:8080/camunda/app","type":"String"} 
      } 
   }
}
```

Java Service Task

```
public class ParseRequest implements JavaDelegate {

@Override
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception
{

// Tried one way as below not working - execution.getVariable("event") is coming null

 String jo1 = JSONObject.quote(execution.getVariable("event").toString());
 JsonValue event2 = SpinValues.jsonValue((String) jo1).create();        
 String catValue = event2.getValue().prop("cat").toString();


// Tried as below not working getting Error - org.camunda.bpm.engine.variable.impl.value.NullValueImpl cannot be cast to org.camunda.spin.plugin.variable.value.JsonValue

JsonValue customer = execution.getVariableTyped("event");
String catValue2 = customer .getValue().prop("cat").toString();

}
```

USing Camunda for the first time in our project . Any help is appreciated .
please guide me here

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: It is necessary to know what you are doing. Please post you process model. We also need to know where do you define the variables and on which scope.

Comment: Which JSON library is being used is irrelevant. The issue obviously has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Zelldon's comment is relevant. It might be useful to write a debugging block, iterating over the "execution.getVariables()" map, to see what variables, if any, are defined.

Comment: The Variables I am getting it from the User input , We have exposed a Camunda Rest APi and are starting the process whenever user calls this process. Its a simple process just receive and then we have got a user task to approve or reject the request.

Comment: I got it working after I changed the JSON format as                                      {
  "variables": {
     "cat" : {"value" : "abc", "type" : "String"},
     "reason": {"value":"abc Changes","type":"String"},
     "link": {"value":"http://localhost:8080/camunda/app","type":"String"} 
   }
}

Comment: Am am retreiving it as JSONObject.quote(execution.getVariable("variableName").toString());